# Find MaxNonZeroPosition of a scale in a decimal

Tags: sql-server

I have a scenario, wherein I need a sql query to find out the MaxNonZeroPosition in a scale of every decimal column of a database using SQL Server.
For ex: 43321.70090100, Max nonZero Position is 6 here.

Comment: how is come 6 can you please explain, so we have better idea

Comment: So in the second part of the decimal .70090100, digit 1 is the maxnonzero digit.. Since it is at position 6, it becomes MaxNonZeroPosition. If I am to give another ex: 221123.812000430035000, here 5 is at position 12, is the MaxNonZeroDigit and hence 12 is it's MaxNonZeroPosition.

Comment: If HoneyBadger or PSK helped you please consider [accepting their answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Accepting answers rewards the contributor, helps others to find a working solution and, in this particular case, settles a debate.

Answer (score 3):

In order to reduce complexity I've put part in a subquery. This should give you what you need:

```
DECLARE @T DECIMAL(20, 12) = 43321.70090100

SELECT  LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), SS)) - PATINDEX('%[^0]%', REVERSE(SS))
FROM    (
            SELECT  @T Ori
            ,       SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @T), CHARINDEX('.', @T), LEN(@T)) SS
        ) Sub
```

Comment: for 43321.71290100 also it is returning 6, which looks incorrect

Comment: Looks very correct to me. The last non zero character is the same, regardless of what precedes it.

Comment: this piece of code seems to be working fine for a decimal value. how can I use this code to find the MaxNonZeroPosition of a column of decimal type  in a given table.

Comment: In the subquery add a from clause, and instead of the variable select the column you need.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

```
declare @test decimal(20, 12) = 221123.812000430035000
select len(replace(@test, 0, ' ')) - charindex('.', @test)
```

Comment: Very good, you don't even need rtrim since trailing spaces are ignored anyway.

Comment: You are right! Thanks. Forgot about it. Updated the query